# How to make two boxes 'sit on top' of each other?

Tags: tables, boxes

I'm struggling to find a way to recreate the following image.

Any tips or advice would be great.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Here is a tip: have a look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: looks great thank you! @Schrödinger'scat

Comment: By the way, the term for this is "drop shadow", which should help in your searches.

Comment: Lovely stuff. Thank you @don

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,width=5in,%center upper,
        drop fuzzy shadow={shadow xshift=\boxShadowOfset, shadow yshift=-1.2\boxShadowOfset, shadow blur steps=6,fill=cyan},
        boxrule=4pt,sharp corners,colframe=cyan,colback=white!10]

        dddd

        dddd

    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```